# String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace in vb.net throw error if value is dbnull.value

Tags: exception, vb.net-2010, dbnull

`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valuefromDB)` throws error if `valuefromDB` is `dbnull.value`

Is that correct??

I thought of this function will also handles the `dbnull.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had Option Strict On your code would never have compiled, because the `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` method on string accepts a `string` type, `DBNull` isn't a string type (it's DBNull), and at a guess your `valuefromDB` variable is of type `Object`.

The IsNull in the name `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is actually referring to the CLRs `null` which in VB is `Nothing`, not `DBNull`

You can either check for both `DBNull` and `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` or as pointed out by Emaad Ali, use the VB function `IsNothing`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

[DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx) does not equal null.

Try something like:

```
If Not DbNull.Value.Equals(valuefromDB)...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes is correct..

From msdn:

Indicates whether a specified string is Nothing, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.

Nothing is not null, so your string can be nothing or empty, but a dbnull is another different value for it :).